# Fixed! A strange error in chat server using boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, server

I have to make a synchronous chat server using boost. I almost completed the server code, it may be still far away from what it should be, but I got very strange error that I couldn't find anything about in Internet. I really want to fix it before continuing but I don't know how. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<map>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

#include<boost/thread.hpp>
#include<boost/bind.hpp>
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket_ptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<string> string_ptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr< list<socket_ptr> > clientList_ptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr< list<string> > nameList_ptr;

const int THREADS = 1;

io_service service;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 30001));
boost::mutex mtx;
clientList_ptr clientList(new list<socket_ptr>);
nameList_ptr nameList(new list<string>);
boost::asio::streambuf buff;
time_t timer;

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

bool clientSentExit(string_ptr message)
{
    return message->find("exit") != string::npos;
}

void disconnectClient(socket_ptr clientSock, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    boost::system::error_code ec = error;
    auto position = find(clientList->begin(), clientList->end(), clientSock);

    clientSock->shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
    clientSock->close(ec);
    clientList->erase(position);

    cout << "Client Disconnected! " << clientList->size() << " total clients" << endl;
}

void do_processing(socket_ptr sock, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!clientList->empty())
        {
            mtx.lock();

            boost::asio::streambuf buff;
            size_t bytes_transferred = boost::asio::read_until(*sock, buff, '\n');

            buff.commit(bytes_transferred);
            std::istream istrm(&buff);

            string_ptr msg(new string(""));
            std::getline(istrm, *msg);
            msg->push_back('\n');
            buff.consume(buff.size());

            if(clientSentExit(msg) || error)
            {
                disconnectClient(sock, error);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "ChatLog: " << *msg << endl;

                for(auto& cliSock : *clientList)
                {
                    if (cliSock->is_open() && cliSock != sock)
                    {
                        cout << "Sending: " << time(&timer) << endl;
                        sock->write_some(buffer(*msg));
                    }
                }
            }

            mtx.unlock();
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::thread_group threads;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Waiting for clients...\n";
        socket_ptr clientSock(new tcp::socket(service));

        acceptor.accept(*clientSock);
        clientList->emplace_back(clientSock);
        threads.create_thread(boost::bind(do_processing, clientSock, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    threads.join_all();
    getc(stdin);

     return 0;
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
In file included from /sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from /sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:30,
                 from /sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:22,
                 from /sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12,
                 from /sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from server.cpp:9:
/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of \u2018void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, const boost::system::error_code&); A = boost::_bi::list0; A1 = boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >; A2 = boost::arg<1> (*)()]\u2019:
/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:895:50:   required from \u2018boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = void; F = void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, const boost::system::error_code&); L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >, boost::arg<1> (*)()>; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]\u2019
/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:116:17:   required from \u2018void boost::detail::thread_data<F>::run() [with F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >, const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > >, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >]\u2019
**server.cpp:218:1:   required from here
/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:315:56: error: no match for \u2018operator[]\u2019 (operand types are \u2018boost::_bi::list0\u2019 and \u2018boost::arg<1>()\u2019)
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);**
```

The numbers in the "required from here" statements are wrong because I have many comments which I want to keep in the IDE, but deleted here. The actual line in which the error occurs is the very last line of the code - with the '}' that closes the main function.

I would be grateful for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed now. As they told me, it's something like a confrontation between

```
const boost::system::error_code& error
```

and

```
boost::asio::placeholders::error.
```

They told me that these error codes are not needed, they are required if the chat server is asynchronous, but here the thread group cannot send an error code.

I'm not sure if I have understood perfectly everything and sorry if the answer seems badly written. Removing the error codes everywhere except for:

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
```

fixed the problem.